# Outputting main menu in full in page.tpl.php

Tags: 7, routes, theming

I'm using the code below to print my main menu in page.tpl.php:

```
<?php
$main_menu = menu_navigation_links('main-menu');
print theme('links', array(
'links' => $main_menu,
'attributes' => array(
'id' => 'main-menu',
'class' => array('links', 'clearfix'),
),

'heading' => array(
'text' => t('Main menu'),
'level' => 'h2',
'class' => array('element-invisible'),
),
));
?>
```

However, it is only outputting the top-level menus of my navigation. Is there a piece of code I can add that will output submenus too?

Comment: Have you tried changing/using/including the `$level` argument to https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/function/menu_navigation_links/7 ?

Comment: OK thanks - could you please tell me where I could add the argument to my code?

Comment: umm, `$main_menu = menu_navigation_links('main-menu', RIGHT_HERE);`, eg, `$main_menu =menu_navigation_links('main-menu', 1);` would go down one level, `$main_menu = menu_navigation_links('main-menu', 2);` would go down two, etc.

Comment: Wow totally worked! :-) thanks, @Jimajamma - could you please post this as an answer below, so I can select as the correct answer? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Calling [menu_navigation_links()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_navigation_links/7) with only the menu name by default provides only the top level links.  To delve deeper you need to provide the second `$level` argument, eg:

```
$main_menu =menu_navigation_links('main-menu', 1);
```

will provide the top and next level links, and:

```
$main_menu =menu_navigation_links('main-menu', 2);
```

will provide one level deeper.

Comment: I tried to use <?php $main_menu =menu_navigation_links('main-menu', 1); ?> on page.tpl.php and nothing print out. Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you actually `print` it after setting it above?

Comment: :P forgot to print $main_menu